# Trying to get an the pokerstove api to work

Tags: c++, git, boost, visual-studio-2015

I want to mess around with pokerstove, but I'm having some issues.

"Windows

Getting boost to work under windows can be a bit of a challenge. One of the easier ways is to install precompiled librares. There is a batch of them available at sourceforge. If you're working with Visual Studio 2010, you will probably need the 32 bit libraries. boost precomplied libraries

Under windows, the cmake gui can be used to construct solution and project files for Visual Studio 2010. To do this, browse source to locate the programs directory git/pokerstove/programs. Then create a build dir for the project. At the bottom of the gui click Configure, then Generate. You may have to edit the git/pokerstove/programs/CMakeLists.txt to point cmake to your installation of boost.

Once you've done that, you should be able to select

Menu->Build->Build Solution
to build the sample program."

Those are the instructions it gives to windows users. I did most of that and tried to build solution, but I'm getting these errors. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIbrL.png
I've tried moving around my boost folder with no luck.

Comment: "I did most of that" - what, specifically, did you skip?

Comment: Don't use links to pictures of text; copy the actual error text. And first copy it into your favorite search engine.